# Get back to Linux shell on chromebook

Tags: chromebook

I've installed the Linux subsystem on my chromebook. I have EMACS installed and it's in my launcher. I can get to the shell by running EMACS and doing a M-X shell. However, I can't figure out how to get a regular shell back. How do I just open another shell window?

Comment: The _Emacs_ Text Editor is not that evil. By installing itself, it has not removed the access to a Terminal. Just try to search for a Terminal Icon somewhere.

Comment: Ah. I type "Terminal" into the search dot.